# Azure Function runs into System.Net.Sockets.SocketException

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-functions, tcpclient, socketexception

I have AzureFunctions app with 2 HTTP trigered functions. Both are direved from same class but use different urls to fetch data.
Every day Azure Data Factory pipeline triggers 1st HTTP function
and another pipeline calls 2nd function within 1 minute

Each function makes around 1300 HTTP requests to 3rd party website and stores each response as separate json file in Blob storage.

The problem is almost each time (but not always) 2nd function throws System.Net.Sockets.SocketException because few outbound requests run into common 21 seconds TCP timeout. 
Strange thing I've notices - it is likely Azure throttles for some reason my outbound requests: first batch takes near 300ms, next sequence takes 4.3sec, then 9.5sec and next batch reaches 21 sec with exception

[Here is image of timing increasing of outbound requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwGkl.jpg)

Exception stacktrace:

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: A connection attempt failed
>   because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of
>   time, or established connection failed because connected host has
>   failed to respond ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A
>   connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly
>   respond after a period of time, or established connection failed
>   because connected host has failed to respond    at
>   System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken)    --- End of inner exception
>   stack trace ---    at
>   System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()    at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()    at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.WaitForCreatedConnectionAsync(ValueTask`1
>   creationTask)    at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
>   at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask,
>   HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean
>   disposeCts)    at
>   FunctionApp.BaseFunc.<>c__DisplayClass7_2.<b__0>d.MoveNext()
>   in
>   E:\vsts-agent-win-1_work\339\s\Services\Host\Controllers\BaseFunc.cs:line
>   102
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at FunctionApp.BaseFunc.ProcessRun(ILogger
>   log, String runId) in
>   E:\vsts-agent-win-1_work\339\s\Services\Host\Controllers\BaseFunc.cs:line
>   122.

FunctionApp is hosted on AppService plan S1 so there is no limit of outbound connections of 600 (I believe so)

Metrics of TCP connections during exception (max was 498):
[Metrics of AzureFunction App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lkour.jpg)

TCP Connections from "Solve problem" helper of AzureFunction App
[Max TCP connections in all states was 502](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cvt7h.jpg)

CPU and Memory of App service plan during exception:
[App Service Plan metrics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbBGb.jpg)

App is .Net Core 2.2

I didn't manage to reproduce this on my local PC. But on Azure it happens almost every day on each environment (dev, test, prod).
After such fail Azure Data Factory makes retry in 5 minutes and it is successfull each time.

Here is code of Base class that is used by both functions:

```
 public abstract class BaseFunc
{
    protected abstract string BlobFolderName { get; }
    protected TelemetryClient telemetryClient;
    private static HttpClient _httpClient;

    static BaseFunc()
    {
        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        handler.MaxConnectionsPerServer = 300;
        _httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
    }
    protected async Task ProcessRun(ILogger log, string runId)
    {
        int processedItems = 0;
        try
        {
            Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

            await Authentication("url", log, runId); //sets default Authorization header

            string getIdeaResult = await _httpClient.GetStringAsync("url");
            JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(getIdeaResult);
            int ideaCount = (int)jsonObject.SelectToken("total_count");

            List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
            string DataPulledDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("connection string");
            CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer cloudBlobContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference("container");

            string getIdsUri = "url" + $"&limit={batchSize}&offset=";
            int iterations = (int)Math.Ceiling((decimal)ideaCount/batchSize);

            for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
            {
                string result = await _httpClient.GetStringAsync("url" + i * 50);
                JObject jsonIdsObject = JObject.Parse(result);
                int[] ideaIds = jsonIdsObject["content"].Children().Values<int>("id").ToArray();
                foreach (int id in ideaIds)
                {
                    tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
                    {
                        string content = null;
                        using (var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "url"+ id))) //Exception is thrown on this line
                        {
                            content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                        }
                        CloudBlockBlob cloudBlockBlob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference($"{DataPulledDate}/{BlobFolderName}/ideaId-{id}.json");
                        await cloudBlobContainer.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
                        await cloudBlockBlob.UploadTextAsync(content);
                        Interlocked.Increment(ref processedItems);
                    }));
                }
            }
            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
            sw.Stop();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.LogError(ex, "{RunId}: Run failed. {Items} items processed successfully, Exception: {Exception}.", runId, processedItems, ex.ToString());
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (telemetryClient != null)
            {
                telemetryClient.Flush();
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code of Function itself:

```
namespace FunctionApp
{
    public class GetIdeas : BaseFunc
    {
        public GetIdeas(TelemetryClient telemetryClient)
        {
            this.telemetryClient = telemetryClient;
        }

        protected override string BlobFolderName { get => "folder"; }
        protected override string GetItemUrl { get => "url"; }

        [FunctionName("GetIdeasFn")]
        public async Task Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = null)] HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
        {
            await ProcessRun(log, $"GetIdeasFn - {DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks}");
        }
    }
}
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you creating a new `BaseFunc` for each connection? https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

Comment: @Neil thank you for reply. No - Added code of function to initial question

Comment: How often do you create a `new GetIdeas`? If it is once per 'call' then you are falling foul of the link I posted.

Comment: @Neil I don't instantiate GetIdeas. It is entry point for Azure Function. This is like WebJob that runs with "Always On" setting. So should run always. "Run" is called from outside by Http call

Comment: Sorry, I missed the `static` on the `BaseFunc` constructor.

Comment: As the error is actually a connection issue, perhaps the problem is not your code, but the server you are connecting to.

Comment: I can't reproduce this exception locally from my PC - server works perfect even if I run both functions simultaneously and with much more MaxConnectionsPerServer. But on Azure it fails even if MaxConnectionsPerServer=50. Even when I set _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = true; that exception appears sometimes

Comment: Try from cmd.exe >Ping -t -l 65500 ServerName I had similar issue a few weeks ago and PING had errors with large sizes.

Comment: @jdweng thanks however don't know how this can identify issue.
tried with -l 35000 - it is ok and with -l 40000 starts to return timeouts

Reply from xx.56.4.66: bytes=35000 time=142ms TTL=45

with -l 40000
Request timed out.

Comment: The TTL is indicating that the PING went through 5 routers/servers.  The TTL is normally set to 50 and decrements by 1 every time it is forwarded.  You should try same between different machines to see if same occurs.Timeout is normally 5 seconds so I so not know why it is timing out with 142msec unless somebody changed the timeout in the application.After 5 seconds a retry occurs so maybe the timeout is due to a retry.  I would use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and see if retries are occurring (same sequence number is repeated).I'm suspecting the server is overloaded and not responding.

Comment: You may want to use task manager on server and see what the load is.

Comment: @jdweng server is not overloaded. I can run my app locally and load it pretty well so 3k requests are processed within 20 seconds without any exceptions. Unfortunately I can't check task manager because it is SaaS application

Comment: Since it is 5 hops it can be any machine in the route.  With 40000 do you see the data coming back late?  How late?  Does 5 hops make sense?

Comment: Are there other web apps or function apps running on your ' AppService plan S1' ? Have you checked your overall TCP connections on the whole app service plan not only the function app?

Comment: @SebastianAchatz yes I did check. Here is [metrics](http://prntscr.com/pa4pv6)  for AppService plan. The total maximum in different states was 1003 connections. I believe 481 (Time wait) are from 1st run of function and 422 for current run that was failed.
My plan hosts only single application - this function app.

Comment: Can you please make your TelemetryClient static too and re-test. That should reduce pressure on Http connections to AppInsights dramatically.

Comment: @SebastianAchatz thank you for suggestion. I tried this change. On dev environment where schedule is set to trigger each function once per hour I don't see failures as for last 4 runs. However on test env where pipeline runs only once per day It failed as usual: first function - ok, second one - failed due to System.Net.Sockets.SocketException. And truly said I don't see reason how static TelemetryClient can help here. Each function sets its own TelemetryClient injected into ctor each time it is instantiated (only for first time as AlwaysOn=true).

Comment: Ah sorry ok I missed the part that you let the TelemetryClient be injected but never mind. Static is fine here too. Did you then register the TelemetryClient as Singleton in the DI container? Can you also try to check the targets (hosts) of the TCP connections? That could give an additonal indicator about the type of connection.

Comment: Your fan-out (foreach loop) has not the ability to scale on function level. One good option would be to use Durable Functions extensions and a "classic" fan-out in order to enable the function runtime to scale for you on larger sets. (In case you do not need a fan-in try a storage queue instead) If you want to stay "in-process un-scaled" you should def. try to manage your concurrency level on the outgoing "traffic" by a SemaphoreSlim to a reasonable level.

Comment: @SebastianAchatz Thank you. I restricted concurrency by SemaphoreSlim with only 20 concurrent threads. Problem seems gone. But strange that HttpHandler.MaxConnectionsPerServer = 20 doesn't help in same way. So root of the problem is still unknown. It is not sockets exhaustion because for that case they have specific exception description "System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions." but mine was "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time..."

Comment: @JekaDeveloper Did you ever found the root cause of the problem?

Comment: @eyal no, I restricted spamming of Task objects with SemaphoreSlim and it became smooth. I suspect it is some internal Azure anti-ddos mechanism but didn't find prove for that.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but in my case, had a code patch having an long looping mechanism that was creating hundreds of requests to Microsoft GraphApi and without responding to one request it was creating another. Corrected & issue fixed!